# how can I add an image to datagrid hyperlink using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid

I have a datagrid in my web project 
and I have a hyperlink column

```
 asp:HyperLinkColumn HeaderText="Mal (Etrafli Melumat ucun Linke
      Toxunun)" DataNavigateUrlField="ProductID"
      DataNavigateUrlFormatString="./product.aspx?ProductID={0}"
      DataTextField="ProductName" Target="_self"
```

How can I update the databound data to display the image here ?

Comment: Try to add template column.

Comment: can you example with my script? i need give parametr from datagrid to antoher page DataNavigateUrlField="ProductID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="./product.aspx?

Comment: I assume that you want to set image within hyperlink, correct? If so you can use imageURL property of hyperlink. OR if you want something else. Please confirm.